# How to apply multiple clustering algorithms to same dataset and make comparison?

Tags: clustering

I've a dataset and I want to implement K-Means, Fuzzy C Means, Gaussian Mixture Model, Spectral Graph. After that, I want to see the clusters that I get from different methods. What is the proper way to do that? Or should I only stick one algorithm and try to maximize correctness of that clustering?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the scikit learn API, they have a [section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) dedicated to this topic.

If you want to go further, have a look at chapter 3 "Unsupervised Learning and Preprocessing" of the book **Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists**, there is a section on clustering methods (they also mention the evaluation of clustering methods which is very insightful)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.